# Como adicionar o Font Awesome ao projeto em 2019

Tags: html, css

Antes já te dava o link CSS pra integrar ao projeto ao clicar em "Star for Free".

Comment: É so vc fazer o cadastro e vão liberar um link exclusivo pra vc http://prntscr.com/pduld9 ou então vc pode procurar o CDN em outro lugar tem um monte de site com esse link. Vc tb ainda pode fazer o download e usar diretamente no seu projeto ou colocar no seu servidor